# React axios request. setState can not read response object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

What I want to happen:
I am trying to make a request to google places API and currently I grab the user input (onChange) and send the request out.  When the response from google places comes back I expect an array of places.  With that array of places I want to update my state of sights to the responses array of places.

My Code:

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state= {
            sights: 'cat',
            city:''
        }
    }

    onInputChange(city) {
        this.setState({city});
        this.handleSubmit(city);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        axios.get(
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=attractions+in+" +
            this.state.city +
            "&key=AIzaSyC5d4W-ei6o_C3eCrnJl24nuaeuAemhoJQ",
                    {
                    mode: "no-cors",
                    header: {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Orgin": "http://localhost:8080",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
                        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
                    },
                    withCredentials: true,
                    credentials: "same-origin"
                    }
                )
                .then((res) => console.log(res.data.results))
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({ sights: res.data.results });
                })
                .then(console.log('got here'))
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log("err", err);
                })
        }
    

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>{this.state.city}</h2>
            <h4>{this.state.sights}</h4>
            <input 
                value={this.state.city}
                onChange={(event)=> this.onInputChange(event.target.value)} /> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Search;
```

What I am testing:

```html
.then((res) => console.log(res.data.results))
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.setState({ sights: res.data.results });
                    })
                    .then(console.log('got here'))
```

My console after making a call to google places:

(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

err TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at eval (Search.jsx:63)

got here

So after my console.log of res.data.results I got exactly what I wanted which was an array of google places.

With that array I wanted to assign it to my state of sights but I get the type error of Cannot read property of 'data' of undefined.  This does not make sense to me because I console.log res.data.results and got back an array.  I have checked the response object also and there is a property named data on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing returned in first `then()` to be used in second `then()`. `console.log()` returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are chaining promises.

This line

```
.then((res) => console.log(res.data.results))
```

will return `undefined` which gets processed by the next `then()` in the chain.

So change it to

```
.then((res) => { console.log(res.data.results)); return res })
```

Comment: Set right bracket:
.then((res) => { console.log(res.data.results); return res })

Comment: Thanks, @Vitaliy!